# Rails App/Facebook Post Messages To Users Wall

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have a language learning app that allows users to take a quiz. I would like the user to be able to post the score they receive to facebook, something like "I got a 90% on quiz".

I have a facebook appid and have placed the following code into my application.html.erb file:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'MY_APP_ID',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.2'
    });
  };


  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

When I use the following code in my results.html.erb, the dialog box doesn't open. Any thoughts on why this is or if there is a better method?

```
FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
     link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
     picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
     caption: 'Reference Documentation',
     description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
     message: 'Facebook Dialogs are easy!'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
```

Comment: You are not allowed to prefill message with anything. The user needs to type every single character in the message